# Difficulty in understanding a piecewise function problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am using Stitz-Zeager PreCalculus book and I am not able to fully understand the problem. The Part I am feeling problem in is the c one.

The Problem is as follows: [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufosE.png)

For $n$ copies of the book *Me and my Sasquatch*, a print on-demand company charges $C(n)$ dollars, where $C(n)$ is determined by the formula
$$
C(n)=\left\{\begin{array}{rll}
15n&\text{if}&1\le n\le25\\
13.50n&\text{if}&25\lt n\le50\\
12n&\text{if}&n\gt50
\end{array}\right.
$$
(a) Find and interpret $C(20)$.

(b) How much does it cost to order $50$ copies of the book? What about $51$ copies?

(c) Your answer to (b) should get you thinking. Suppose a bookstore estimates it will sell $50$ copies of the book. How many books can, in fact, be ordered for the same price as those $50$ copies? (Round your answer to a whole number of books.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The price of just getting $50$ books is $50\times \$13.50$. But you could get more than $50$ books for the same amount because once you start paying for over $50$ you can get them at $\$12.00$ per book. So you need to solve

$$x\times\$12.00=50\times\$13.50$$

Comment: Thanks That Really Helped.

Comment: Hello I am unable to judge why did someone down vote my question. Please can you tell me the possible reason?

Comment: @AbdulHannanAli I'm glad it helped :).

Comment: @AbdulHannanAli People down vote things for a variety of reasons, and it's often hard to tell precisely why - but in this case it was probably because someone wanted you to share more of your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: I'll make sure I provide more info next time.

Comment: @AbdulHannanAli: they might remove their downvote if you provide some context (what it is that is giving you trouble with (c) or what you have tried). This would improve the question and make the answer more beneficial to you.